# How can i change the name of my bigcommerce app (the name showing up in app listing)

Tags: bigcommerce, devpartner

I want to change the name of Bigcommerce app. I don't see an option in my developer account. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Get in contact with your partner or app store rep at Bigcommerce, they will be able to help you.